# Unity 3D - forcing GI re-bake after runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a procedurally generated art project. The idea is that after runtime several clay pots/vases are procedurally generated from a lathe/line and rotation script. The pots are located on a circular platform and the camera rotates around this platform.

Pots are generated just in front of the cameras field of vision. Pots are deleted after the pass out of the cameras field of vision. At any given time, there are about 30 vessels.

The script is being changed so that the generation and deletion happens in a large batch while the camera movement is stopped. I would like to force Unity to re-bake GI at this time, but I can't figure out how.

Since none of the objects are moving and there will be a complete pause in all movement (the viewer will not know that the CPU is consumed) I'd like to avoid using realtime GI. Baked GI will allow me to use area lights and more expensive GI settings, but the objects generated after runtime need to be accounted for.

I hope this makes sense. I don't think I am using Unity in a typical fashion, so there is not a lot of documentation about this.

Also, if anyone knows a scripting API to access Lighting -> Object -> Important GI [x]    that would be immensely helpful

I was able to use GameObjectUtility to make all of vessels Lightmap Static, but they need to be GI Important (they generate on top of each other, inside each other, etc.. and they have a slightly specular material)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be a piece-mealed procedurally generated scene. This is briefly mentioned in the [introduction to Global Illumination](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/09/18/global-illumination-in-unity-5/).

You might look into 5.3's scene manager, which allows for making multiple scenes and piecing them together. If you baked in such a scene, I imagine you could combine them together as you wished.